# How to query all entities for today using LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I basically need to get all entities that are scheduled for today. I'm doing this via Spring JPA.

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM AppointmentEntity c WHERE c.appointmentDateTime = CURRENT_DATE")
List<AppointmentEntity> findAllToday();
```

Here's what I have so far. The problem with this one is `appointmentDateTime` is actually a LocalDateTime instance, so it's a *mismatch* with `CURRENT_DATE`.

I've also tried this:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM AppointmentEntity c WHERE DATE(c.appointmentDateTime) = CURRENT_DATE")
```

But it just throws a red underline under the first parenthesis, saying `<expression>, <operator>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected, got '('`

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: just oracle mysql

Comment: @Query("SELECT c FROM AppointmentEntity c WHERE cast(c.appointmentDateTime as Date) = CURRENT_DATE()")

try this